# Entity Framework two virtual properties with different multiplicity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this class with two the same virtual class `Key` for `AdminKey` that is `many is to one` and `List<Key>` for `SharedKey` which is, obviously, `one to many`.

Which goes like an `AdminKey` can open multiple `Door`, and. A `Door` can be opened by many
`SharedKeys`

```
public class Door {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public Key AdminKey { get;set; }
    public List<Key> SharedKey { get;set; }
}

public class Key { 
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public List<Door> DoorCanOpen { get; set; }
    public Door SharedKeyDoor { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Door>()
            .HasOne<Key>(t => t.AdminKey);

modelBuilder.Entity<Door>()
            .HasMany<Key>(t => t.SharedKey);
```

When I ran the migration, the `Key` class is having both `DoorCanOpenId` and `SharedKeyDoor`.

Am I doing a mess with my relationships? How to do this kind of relationship properly>?

Comment: You have `Door`, you have `Key` - where is `Floor` coming from?

Comment: I would just define the many-to-many relationship. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) And maybe add a type to the key table, without any other navigation properties.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - I don't think many-to-many is the right approach. It's not like there are many doors to many keys. There is One Master Key to Many doors; and *independently* One Door to Many shared keys. so, OP's approach is generally sound

Comment: @Felix A master key and a shared key can open many doors. And there's probably a key that can only open one door. I would rather implement specific door / key rules outside the database schema. eg `public Key MasterKey => Keys.Where(k => k.Type == KeyType.Master).SingleOrDefault();`. Or I'd try to model the actual key bidding and use something like bitwise masks to identify all keys that can open a door.

Comment: @Felix my bad, `Floor` should be `Door`.

Comment: OK, now I am totally confused... maybe it *is* better to implement many-to-many relationship as @JeremyLakeman suggested... and then have an attribute that particular key is master key in some way. I don't even quite understand what "master" means in this context (usually, it opens many doors; but then what is shared?!)

Comment: I want it with 2 masters. 
2 scenarios; a. If we talk about `AdminKey` in `Doors` to `Keys` it's the `Doors` that is the master. b. If we talk about `SharedKey` in `Doors` to `Keys`  the `Keys` is the master. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in the `many` class you need to explicitly specify the member variable for the relationship, otherwise EF doesn't know what is the foreign key ID. Also you *do* need Id for the `one` part:

```
public class Door {
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public int AdminKeyId { get;set; }
   public Key AdminKey { get;set; }
   [InverseProperty("SharedKeyDoorId")]
   public List<Key> SharedKey { get;set; }
}

public class Key { 
   public int Id { get;set; }
   [InverseProperty("AdminKeyId")]
   public List<Door> DoorCanOpen { get; set; }
   public int SharedKeyDoorId { get; set; }
   public Door SharedKeyDoor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @felix I can't run update-database. I think it's conflicting with the primary key of `Door` it's saying `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Key_Door_SharedKeyDoorId". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.Door", column 'Id'.` please help.

Comment: drop the database and run from scratch. Or alternatively - you can create the database manually with all relationship; and scaffold the classes. In many cases it's an easier approach. You would have KeyID in Doors table that would indicate the ID of master key; and doorId in the Key table to indicate the door for shared keys. Just make sure you have nullable foreign keys; otherwise, you won't be able to enter data

Comment: You also need the Foreign Key properties to be nullable, or else you won't be able to insert into either table because of the circular dependency.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - heh! that's my last sentence right above your comment ;)